# How to fetch a certain value from a hashtable

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
values = []
values << [ '1', 'one']
values << [ '2', 'two']
values << [ '3', 'three']

one = '1'

puts values[one]
```

The above line throws an exception.

Comment: That's not an array, [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01NHcTM5IA4) is an array. (youtube link) Or you could do `values.class` to get the class of `values`.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: I'm quite certain it is an array. Even `values.class` says so.

Comment: @undur_gongor: you're right, I should have said "that's not a hashtable, this is a hashtable". Serves me right for trying to do a humorous comment.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: My missing sense of humor -- again. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined an array, you want a hash.

```
values = {}
values['1'] = 'one'
values['2'] = 'two'
values['3'] = 'three'

one = '1'
values[one] #=> 'one'
```

That of course you should write:

```
values = {
 '1' => 'one',
 '2' => 'two',
 '3' => 'three',
}

one = '1'    
values[one] #=> 'one'
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not a Hash table; that's an array. `values` has the value: `[['1', 'one'], ['2', 'two'], ['3', 'three']]`

The code you were looking for is:

```
values = {'1' => 'one', '2' => 'two'}
values['3'] = 'three'

one = '1'

puts values[one] # => 'one'
```

Answer (score 1):

Like others have pointed out, its really not a hash table its more like 2-dimensional array. Although not effective to retrieve values this way. An approach to obtain value from this structure could be

```
values.select { |entry| entry[0].eql? '1' }[0][1]
```

Comment: You can also use #assoc to get values from this kind of array.  For example: `values.assoc(one).last`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert an array of key value pairs into a hash:

```
values = []
values << [ '1', 'one']
values << [ '2', 'two']
values << [ '3', 'three']

hash = Hash[values]
hash['1'] # => "one"
```

This uses the `Hash.[]` method, which is described [at this ruby-doc.org page](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D).